# Oracle SQL - If value is a substring of any string in multi-select parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Say you have a parameter `:p_companys` that is a list of values that is multi-selectable:

```
-----------
| company |
-----------
| 50 - ar |
| 55 - ag |
| 62 - hh |
| 70 - nr |
-----------
```

Now say from this list a user selects `50 - ar` and `55 - ag` as their values. The parameter is now a list of those two values.

In our SQL query we're using the company number and checking to see if they're contained in this parameter. The company number is the first 2 digits (50 and 55.) Is there a way to do something like this:

```
select comp -- 50 and 55
from companies
where comp in :p_companys
```

but instead of comparing to the entire string throughout the list we just compare to the first `x` amount of characters (essential taking a sub string of all values in the parameter?)

Comment: From where and how the value will be passed as `:p_companys` and what is the datatype of `:p_companys` ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 `:p_companys` is a list of `string` values. The user will have a menu with all possible companies, they can select one or more companies, and that will be passed to the SQL query as `:p_companys`

Comment: Yes i got that but in which format ? (why i am asking there is no such list concept in oracle directly) is it JSON or how ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 here is a website that references the tool I'm using to create these lists: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e18862/T527073T560157.htm

If I'm not mistaken once the `:p_companys` parameter is inserted into the SQL query it can be referenced similar to how you would say `where x in ('str1', 'str2', ... 'strx')`

Comment: It's not clear from that page what the datatype of the parameter is, and I'm not clear which one you are using out of the several parameter types that it mentions. It makes a big difference to the answer if it's a comma-separated string or a collection, for example.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I've been dealing with pretty vague documentation throughout using this software. 

I ended up solving the issue by adding a second column to my `:p_company` parameter query. If you have two columns Oracle will use the first column for menus (so this is where I put the human readable string) and the second column (raw company number) is used in the SQL query. I then just used `where comp in (:p_companys)`

Comment: @CodyMaxie `in (:bindvar)` cannot work, unless somehow `:bindvar` is treated as a substitution variable by BI Publisher. Is it not possible to find out what is actually used, in order to begin to answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an undetermined number of parameters in your input selection, I think you need to use a combination of `regexp` and `connect by level`

Something like this should do the trick

```
with t as 
(
SELECT regexp_substr(:p_companys ,'[^,]+',1,level) as mycol FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(:p_companys ,'[,]')+1
) select comp from companies
where comp in ( select mycol from t ) 
;
```

Example

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 varchar2(1) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ( 'A' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ( 'B' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ( 'C' );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t ;

C
-
A
B
C
```

Now, let's test when the input variable is a list of strings

```
with x as
    (
    SELECT regexp_substr('A,B,C' ,'[^,]+',1,level) as mycol FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT('A,B,C' ,'[,]')+1
   ) select * from t where c1 in  ( select mycol from x )
   ;

C
-
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in WHERE clause.

If you expect 2 digits you can use regexp like this:
`REGEXP_SUBSTR(comp, '\d\d') in ('50', '55')`

Or if you just want to cut from your string the first 2 characters:
`SUBSTR(comp, 1, 2) in ('50', '55')`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out you don't have to use just a single row in Oracle when dealing with lists. You can use two rows, and I've found that in doing so the second row is treated as the value that is passed to SQL. The first row is treated as the value shown to the users. So you could have a list like this:

```
---------------------------
|    comp_desc   |  comp  |
---------------------------
|  50 - retail   |   50   |
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
|  90 - lodging  |   90   |
```

Where the user will see column `comp_desc` values passed in the menu select, but the SQL query will be given the `comp` column's values via the `:p_company` value.

So using this setup we can simply use `where comp in (:p_company)` (note that the parenthesis is needed here)

Comment: What do you mean by "use just a single row" and "dealing with lists"? What is a list? What value is passed to SQL?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e18862/T527073T560157.htm this page should describe what a list is. Basically you can define a list (in this case a sql query) that is ran and generates values for an end user to select from. What the user selects is then passed to the main query as parameter `:p_company`.

Apologies if this is confusing. This functionality is part of Oracle's BI Publisher suite, which is what I'm working with. I'm not sure if these lists are a standard Oracle DB component or if they're unique to BI Publisher.

Comment: The page doesn't say what a list is in technical terms, just how to work with them in the BI Publisher user interface, which I doubt many people have used or heard of. None of this is standard database functionality so none of the answers are relevant. I'd suggest tagging oracle-bi-publisher but I'm afraid there isn't one.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks for the tip. I wasn't aware that this wasn't a standard feature within Oracle DB. I'm pretty sure that since the list is a standard Oracle SQL query that it would be a table, which you can reference like any other table.

Comment: In your example, `where comp in (:p_company)` - that syntax wouldn't work if `:p_company` was a table name or a collection, or if it was substituted for a table name (you'd need a subquery). Maybe BI Publisher substitutes it for a list of literals. You could tell if you could find the cursor text in v$sql.